# How to get coefficients in sympy complex expressions/ Python

Tags: python, sympy, coefficients

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
xgg8, xgg9, abb3 = sp.symbols("xgg8, xgg9, abb3")
expr = 3 + xgg9 + (xgg8)**2*abb3 + a*(xgg8)*2 + xgg9**2/xgg8
expr.coeff(xgg8)
expr.coeff(xgg9)
```

I can get the right result.

But if I add a coefficent like "abb3**3*", I get a zero.

```
expr = abb3**3*(3 + xgg9 + (xgg8)**2*abb3 + a*(xgg8)*2 + xgg9**2/xgg8)
expr.coeff(xgg8)
expr.coeff(xgg9)
```

Any one knows why? How can I get the right result?

Comment: Use `expand` before calling `coeff`.

Comment: `Expr.coeff` is literal - it doesn't try multiply out the coefficients in any way. But, as Oscar points out, `expr.expand().coeff(ann3**3)` should work.